# Documenting external types with TypeDoc

Tags: javascript, typescript, typedoc

I have two files, file A and file B. File A uses a class from file B. My goal is to reference the TypeDoc output for a class used in file B in the TypeDoc output for file A. I can't seem to do this.

I know you can reference a symbol contained in the same file with TypeDoc with double brackets, like `[[Foo]]`, but this didn't work for an external type like this.

```js
/** Trying to reference [[FileB.InnerClass]] like this doesn't work. */
// This here is what I want to include
export type InnerClass = FileB.InnerClass;

// More code...
```

Is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

yes, it's possible.

1. correct the comment.
2. You don't have to enter the file name but you have to import object from  file using `import`

```
import { InnerClass } from './FileB';

/**
 * See the [[InnerClass]] for more details.
 */
export type innerClass = InnerClass;
```

3. To generate docs, run the following command.

when `typedef` it's global use this command:

`typedoc --out ./docs --target ES6 ./src/`

or this when it's local:

`npx typedoc --out ./docs --target ES6 ./src/`

- `./docs` is folder where generate documentation.
- `./src/` is folder where your code is.
- `--target ES6` version of JavaScript.

If you want to show only classes without different modules, use this flag `--mode file`:

`npx typedoc --out ./docs --mode file --target ES6 ./src/`

for more info, see [documentation](https://typedoc.org/).

Comment: This was extremely useful, thank you so much! I do have a follow up question to this question that I posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57298054/linking-to-external-library-documentation-with-typedoc could you take a look?