# Linking to external library documentation with TypeDoc

Tags: javascript, typescript, typedoc

I have a TypeScript project, and I'm using TypeDoc to generate documentation for it. In my project I am using an external library that has its own existing documentation. In the TypeDoc output for my project I want to link the reader to the documentation for the external library without having to manually insert a URL.

The closest I've come to a solution is placing double brackets in the code comments around what I want to link to, like this:

```js
/** I want to link to something called [[Foo]] */
```

But this doesn't seem to work for types in an external library.

Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: Is [externalsymbollinkmappings](https://typedoc.org/options/comments/#externalsymbollinkmappings) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use following syntax by putting text between square brackets `[]` and url between parenthesis `()`.

```
[Text to be displayed](URL)
```

For example: Link to an `npm` module called `pg-structure`.

`[pg-structure](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-structure)`

I also usually link to related paragraph by copying from `npm` link icon left to title. (See icon left to `Synopsis` title in example picture below)

[image]